# use angular-cli project with visual studio asp.net empty web app?

Tags: angular, visual-studio-2017, angular-cli

I have created an empty asp.net web application in VS 2017. Removed all .NET references and config files. Created an Angular-cli project in the same project folder.

Now i want to do the following:
-Right click on "project file -> Debug -> start new instance" -- should build the app with "ng build" and serve the application with "ng serve -o"

How can this be achieved?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please take a look at [Angular CLI Templates](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=AndreyFomin.AngularCLIProjectTemplate). This is a set of two templates that create Angular CLI applications in Visual Studio 2017. There is a template that adds Angular CLI to an existing ASP.NET Core project. Another template creates an Angular CLI application as a static website project.

Disclaimer: I am the author of the templates. The source code is available on GitHub.